# Laravel nested queries

Tags: php, laravel

I am working on a product and I need to fetch data on some form

My tables are

Courses :

> id
>
> title
>
> .... other fields

Course_term

> id
>
> teacher_id
>
> course_id
>
> group
>
> .... other fields

Teacher

> id
>
> name
>
> .... other fields

It's many to many relationship !

I need my teacher Model to return the courses belongs to it on this form

```
[
  {
   course_id: '',
   title: '',
   groups: ['A', 'B'] // the groups the teacher has
  }
]
```

I already got the courses but it's on this format

```
[
  {
   course_id: '',
   title: '',
   pivot: {
     group: 'A',
   }
  },

  {
   course_id: '',
   title: '',
   pivot: {
     group: 'B',
   }
  }
]
```

The code is

```
return $this->belongsToMany(Course::class,CourseTerm::class)
            ->withPivot('group');
```

Any suggestions ?

Comment: tried to remove `withPivot('group')` and append `with('group')` to your controller's code?

Comment: brooo, it's almost working, Thanks man

Comment: Almost? what do you get now?

Comment: Everythings works good now, Thank you so much I was just editing the query that's why I said almost. much respect :)

Comment: Glad I could help, I made my comment an answer if you're willing to accept it for new vistors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to remove `withPivot('group')` and append `with('group')` to your controller's code

```php
return $this->belongsToMany(Course::class,CourseTerm::class);
```

And in your controller

```php
Teacher::with('group');
```